# Use API Gateway as http proxy with uri (request path+variable query params) passthrough

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to do some vary basic routing with API Gateway.
I need to achieve the following scenario:

- user makes request xxxx-execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/**api1**/a/b/../n?param1=val1&parma2=val2...&paramn=valn request should go to **api1**.back.end/a/b/../n?param1=val1&parma2=val2...&paramn=valn
- user makes request xxxx-execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/**api2**/a/b/../n?param1=val1&parma2=val2...&paramn=valn request should go to **api2**.back.end/a/b/../n?param1=val1&parma2=val2...&paramn=valn
- user makes request xxxx-execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/*****/a/b/../n?param1=val1&parma2=val2...&paramn=valn request should go to **api3**.back.end/a/b/../n?param1=val1&parma2=val2...&paramn=valn

The routing should be done based on first path index after stage, and everything else after that should be passed to the http backend (like a transparent proxy).

In other words, if path index 1 is **api1**, forward request to **api1**.back.end with full URI after path index 1;   if path index 1 is **api2**, forward request to **api2**.back.end with full URI after path index 1; if path index 1 is **anything else** than the explicit values api1 or api2, forward request to **api3**.back.end with full URI after path index 1;

How would I achieve this, without adding any extra layers (lambda, cloudfront, ec2, etc.) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Gateway does not support this use case today; each method and path must be explicitly defined in your API definition.

Supporting such passthrough proxies is a request we have heard from other customers and we may consider supporting it in future updates to the service.

**UPDATE 09/20/2016**: I'm happy to announce that we've launched a set of features to allow for proxying of requests as described above. See our [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/) for more details.

Comment: While not ideal, you could perform this routing/redirection in Lambda, could you not? Either by returning a redirect or proxying a call to the target server, perhaps?

Comment: @ericpeters0n API Gateway would still need to support variable or "greedy" resource paths, which it does not. Currently you need to define every resource/method in your API Gateway definition and map this to an integration (e.g. Lambda).

Comment: Gist (for single-level path): `create-resource --path-part '{proxy+}' --parent-id {ID of / root resource}`; `put-method --request-parameters method.request.path.proxy=true`; `put-integration --type HTTP_PROXY --uri 'http://downstream.domain/{basefile}' --request-parameters integration.request.path.basefile=method.request.path.proxy`; `create-deployment`